# How i can solve this issue on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> aapt2 is missing on 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe'
Information:BUILD FAILED in 1s
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you ask a question here, it already means that you have some issue. And adding `android-studio-3.0` tag already means that you have issue with android studio. Please edit your question title for it to make any sense.

Comment: Did you check that the file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe actually exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using Java 7. Please Update it to Java 8, it seems to be a java version issue.